# Bootstrap Popover placed with JQuery insertAfter Very Different Than Hardcoded Bootstrap Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

> I am getting very different results when I try to insertAfter the same popover link that has been hard coded to show you what I am expecting. After you see how this hardcoded popover looks, comment it out, and see how it changes when you do an on blur validation of the blank field triggering the same popover to be inserted after the label. I am not sure if this has to do with inline properties of the label element, but the popover when placed with the insertAfter has a one line quality about it. I am not sure what is going on here or how I can overcome this. Thanks.

```js
(function($) {

  $(window).load(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

    function getLabel(el) {
      return $("label[for=" + $(el).attr("id") + "]");
    }

    function insertInvalidIconAndErrorMsg(label, errorTitle, errorMsg) {
      $("<a title='" + errorTitle + "' data-toggle='popover' class='invalidIconAndErrorMsg' data-trigger='hover' data-placement='top' data-content='" + errorMsg + "'>Error!</a>").insertAfter($(label));
    }

    function validateInputText(el) {
      var label = getLabel(el);
      if (!$(el).val().trim().length > 0) {
        insertInvalidIconAndErrorMsg(label, "Required Field", "Required Fields Can not Be Left Blank.")

      }
    }

    $(":input").on('blur', (function() {
      validateInputText(this);
    }));
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
          <!-- COMMENT THIS LINE OUT AFTER YOU HOVER OVER LINK--><a title='errorTitle' data-toggle='popover' class='invalidIconAndErrorMsg' data-trigger='hover' data-placement='top' data-content='Required Field Can Not Be Left Blank'>Error!</a>
          <div class="grpWrapper">
            <div class="input-group form-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon color">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x fa-fw color-icon1"></i>
       </span>
              <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="First Name..." />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/t1e7LL7q/) jsFiddle. So what is different? (I did modify the js a little for the popover to work)

Comment: $('[data-toggle="popover"]').off('popover').popover(); Is this what you added to make it work? It looks like it should now. What does this do?

Comment: I don't see what you could have changed that made the difference here. Looks like you just switched popover off after the insert. Still don't see what you changed to affect the behavior. Looks good though.

Comment: I've tried to explain this as an answer. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the line `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` is executed - it adds popover to all existing element with attribute `data-toggle=popover`. But it cannot add popovers to elements which are not yet added to the DOM. In your case you are adding the element dynamically - so after the element is added the `popover` function/event needs to be defined again.

This can easily be done by writing `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` again. But as this function can get executed multiple times so multiple events (doing the exact same thing) will get attached to the element. So we need to remove the existing event and then reattach the event. This can be done using the `off` function.

So finally it becomes `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').off('popover').popover();`

jSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/t1e7LL7q/)

Comment: Thanks Taleeb. I appreciate your thorough answer in explaining this to me.